# Convert array<String^> to System::String^

Tags: .net, arrays, string, c++-cli

How do I convert CLI array to String^ ?

This is my example:

```
int main(array<String^>^ args)
{
    Application::Run(gcnew Main_Form(args));
    return 0;
}

Main_Form(array<String^> ^params)
{
    if (params->Length > 0)
    {
        String^ start_param;
        //how do i convert the array to normal String^ ?
    }
}
```

Comment: The same way you convert an array of integers to an integer, I suppose.

Comment: Do you just want to append them all together? Have a delimiter? What specifically are you stuck on? (And this is **not** C++ code, it is C++/CLI – please respect the language tags.)

Comment: Lets forget about C++ and CLI for a while. Take an abstract array of strings. How do you want to convert it to just ONE string?

Comment: Thanks for the answers so I made that:    if(params->Length > 0)
    {   
     for(int i = 0; i <= params->Length; i++)
     {
      start_param + params[i];
     }
    } but it keeps crashing

Comment: Make that `i < params->Length` – as-is, you're indexing one past the last element of the array.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Can you please give me a small example?

Comment: It's a one-character modification of the code _you just showed_ – instead of `i <= params->Length` do `i < params->Length`...

Comment: Ahh thanks, now it doesn´t crash anymore, but the output is nothing in the end, seems so that start_param is completly empty

Comment: I still need help please, anyone?

Comment: String^ start_param = String::Join(" ", args);

Comment: @ildjarn, although the question is a bit unclear, I think the answer is what you wrote in the last comment. Why didn't you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a year I found it out myself :)

```
String^ start_param = String::Concat(params);
```